# Unable to create google group with Terraform resource google_cloud_identity_group

Tags: permissions, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

The following resource is used to create a google group using the terraform `google-beta` and version `3.36`:

```
resource "google_cloud_identity_group" "cloud_identity_group_basic" {
  provider = google-beta
  display_name = "aaa bbb"

  parent = "customers/XXX"

  group_key {
    id = "aaa_bbb@evilcorp.com"
  }

  labels = {
    "cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum" = ""
  }
}
```

`terraform plan` tells me that it will create the resource but performing `apply` results in an error (`Actor does not have permission to create group`). The terraform service-account has already a lot of permissions such as `Organization Administrator`, `Google Cloud Managed Identities Admin`, `Google Cloud Managed Identities Domain Admin`, ...

G Suite Domain-wide Delegation also has been tried, but unsure how this might help.

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # google_cloud_identity_group.cloud_identity_group_basic will be created
  + resource "google_cloud_identity_group" "cloud_identity_group_basic" {
      + create_time  = (known after apply)
      + display_name = "aaa bbb"
      + id           = (known after apply)
      + labels       = {
          + "cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum" = ""
        }
      + name         = (known after apply)
      + parent       = "customers/XXX"
      + update_time  = (known after apply)

      + group_key {
          + id = "aaa_bbb@evilcorp.com"
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

google_cloud_identity_group.cloud_identity_group_basic: Creating...

Error: Error creating Group: googleapi: Error 403: Error(2015): Actor does not have permission to create group 'aaa_bbb@evilcorp.com'.
Details:
[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
    "description": "Error(2015): Actor does not have permission to create group 'aaa_bbb@evilcorp.com'.",
    "owner": "domain:cloudidentity.googleapis.com",
    "resourceType": "cloudidentity.googleapis.com/Group"
  }
]

  on groups.tf line 1, in resource "google_cloud_identity_group" "cloud_identity_group_basic":
   1: resource "google_cloud_identity_group" "cloud_identity_group_basic" {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to [use service accounts with Google Groups APIs without domain-wide delegation](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/08/use-service-accounts-google-groups-without-domain-wide-delegation.html) now.

See: Setting up the Groups API / [Assigning an admin role to the service account](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/setup#assigning_an_admin_role_to_the_service_account). This enabled the terraform service-account to create/manage groups.

Comment: Can confirm it to be working. The second link did the trick for me. We also struggled to get that to run for some time.

Answer (score 2):

Building a bit in top of [@Dag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63671740/1776630) answer:

It is also possible to do it through the [Admin Console](https://admin.google.com/u/1/ac/roles).

Actually, I didn't find any other way, as it seems impossible to obtain the `uniqueID` of the *Default Cloud Build Service Account*.

1. Follow the previous link as a Workspace Super User.
2. Click on the *Groups Admin* role.
3. Click in the down arrow in the *Admins* section
4. Finally click on *Assign service accounts* there you can paste
   the service account email (`<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`)

After doing this, it is actually possible to obtain the service accounts `uniqueID`: Just run the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/roleAssignments/list) from the *Directory API* documentation with the roleId (you can get the roleId from the URL you are after point 2) and the customer id that you can obtain from the [Account settings](https://admin.google.com/ac/accountsettings/profile).